# Creating an installable Django app with a 3rd party dependency

Tags: django, pypi

I am in the process of creating an installable `Django` app on `pypi` which can be added to `INSTALLED_APPS`. The app works correctly up to this point.

The problem now is that I wish to use `Django Rest Framework` within my app. Does this mean that users will have to add my app as well as `Django Rest Framework` to their `INSTALLED_APPS` when installing my app?

Is there a way to simply add my app to `INSTALLED_APPS` without the user being aware of or needing to worry about anything else. They don't need to know that I use `Django Rest Framework` *under the hood*?

I have already added `djangorestframework` to my `setup.py` so that it is installed when the user `pip installs` my package. So the questions is around whether or not the user has to explicitly add it to `INSTALLED_APPS`.

Comment: Django's `INSTALLED_APPS` list is only for convenience in that Django automatically searches for templates, static files, urls, models etc. in the listed apps. If you're using DRF just for internal purposes then it doesn't need to be present in `INSTALLED_APPS` list. Think of DRF as a regular Python library which you can import and use however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best you can/(should) do is add rest framework as dependency in your application, and instruct users to add rest framework in installed apps. Because project settings should not be modified pragmatically, should explicitly hard coded and remain read-only within code base.

You should instruct users to add rest framework in installed apps like [this package does](https://django-rest-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html)

One other thing you can do is check whether user have installed 'rest_framework' or not in `ready` hook of your AppConfig class like this

```
class YourAppConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'yourapp'

    def ready(self):
        from django.conf import settings
        if 'rest_framework' not in settings.INSTALLED_APPS:
            raise ImproperlyConfigured('rest_framework must be in installed apps.')
```

It will at least force them to do so.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `djangorestframework` to your [`install_requires`](https://python-packaging.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dependencies.html#specifying-dependencies) in your setup.py.

Then, when your user runs `pip install yourapp`, it will install rest framework as well.

Personally, I would say to add `'yourapp'` and `'rest_framework'` to `INSTALLED_APPS` in your setup instructions. You may be able to find a way to automatically add it, but it might not be worth the effort. As an example Django Debug Toolbar [removed its automatic setup code](https://django-debug-toolbar.readthedocs.io/en/latest/changes.html#id12) to reduce complexity.